# Where should I log in a Service-oriented Architecture in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, error-handling, error-logging

I have a NodeJS app with a Service-oriented architecture; my controllers interacts with services, and services interacts with the data access layer and external APIs. Does anyone know of any best practices for logging with this architecture? Should I mainly log in the controllers? In the services? Or maybe inside the data access layer or wrappers for external APIs?